# Populate TextBox from Database using JQuery or AJAX

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following scenario: 
An SQL 2000 database with a table containing the columns UserID and UserName.
A webpage with TextBox1 and TextBox2.

I need to use JQuery, plain JavaScript or AJAX to accomplish the following:  When I type the UserID in TextBox1 and press the Tab key, TextBox2 will populate with the corresponding UserName.

I have this implementation in ASP.NET using C# and calling a web service,  however I  want to avoid postbacks when doing the table search and I know JavaScript or AJAX is the way to go.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this. The easiest is to use an [UpdatePanel](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx). This will basically be a drop in solution which will work with your existing code.

If you want to use jQuery, you will need to add a webservice or something else to return the data. You can call the webservice with jQuery like this

```
var parameters = { UserId: userId }

$.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://url to webservice",
       data: parameters,
       contentType: "application/json; 
       charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result) {
              $("#id of username field").val(result);
       },
       error: function(e) {  
           alert(e);
       }
});
```

Comment: Will it be better to use val() instead of html().

Comment: Ohh yeah probably, I was thinking the field would be a div

Comment: Thank you very much Bob and Adamantium, I will be testing it shortly. So the $(userNameField).html(result); can be changed to $(userNameField).var(result); ? or both ways will do ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX.

jQuery has some built in [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) functionality.

You can issue an AJAX request to the server and get the result and fill the result to the textbox.